# Python - opening a folder with pictures

Tags: python, image, matrix, file-upload

I have a folder which includes 20 pictures. I want to open the folder and scan all the picture and for every picture create her own matrix.

How can I do this?

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages

path = open(r"C:\Users\yasmin\Desktop\weeds\type1",encoding='utf-8')

# your images in an array
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    # you can show every image
    img.show()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you try to google it? Please share some code.

Comment: @planet260 edited

Comment: i have an error : SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You are missing a `'` at the end of `encoding=`.

Comment: @DavidG thanks , now i got PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\yasmin\\.....'

Answer (score 0):

For Image processing i would suggest PIL: [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html)

For folder and file handling take a look at os library.

Example:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for file in os.listdir(path):
    image = Image.open(os.path.abspath(path + "/" + file))
    pixels = image.load()
```

**EDIT:**

I would make the following changes in loadImages:

```
def loadImages(path):
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        if image[-3:] in ["png", "jpg"]:
            img = PImage.open(path + "/" + image)
            loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages
```

You are missing a directory separator ("/") between folder and filename.
This checks if the file has either jpg or png as extension.

Comment: sorry , I don't understand how to open all the pictures as i want , a litlle new in python

Comment: To me, `from PIL import Image as PImage` is a strong signed that PIL is already known to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem was that you were missing a `'` at the end of `encoding=`. However, you don't need that line at all. `os.listdir()` needs a string which is the path to the folder that contains the images. There is no need to `open` anything which is why you were getting your second, "permission denied" error. Therefore, simply replace:

```
path = open(r"C:\Users\yasmin\Desktop\weeds\type1",encoding='utf-8')
```

with:

```
path = "C:\Users\yasmin\Desktop\weeds\type1"
```